# images parameter from cameraWithTensors() contains empty object when processed on handleCameraStream function

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

**Problem:**

I want to use **cameraWithTensors** from `@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native` api together with expo camera module. (Same with the [documentation](https://js.tensorflow.org/api_react_native/1.0.0/#cameraWithTensors)). **Note** that I am doing this all in bare react-native. I tested expo camera and it is working properly, I then wrapped `expo-camera` with `cameraWithTensors(Camera)` from the api. The camera still renders in my screen (Android) without any problem.

```
return (
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
      <TensorCamera
        // Standard Camera props
        style={StyleSheet.absoluteFill}
        type={CameraType.front}
        // Tensor related props
        cameraTextureHeight={textureDims.height}
        cameraTextureWidth={textureDims.width}
        resizeHeight={416}
        resizeWidth={416}
        resizeDepth={3}
        onReady={handleCameraStream}
        autorender={true}
      />
    </View>
  );
```

Now on getting the frame data from the `TensorCamera`. I copied the function handleCameraStream from the docs.

```
function handleCameraStream(images) {
    console.log('IN HANDLE CAMERA STREAM...');
    console.log(images); // PRINTS EMPTY OBJECT

    const loop = async () => {
      try {
        const nextImageTensor = images.next().value;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('LOOP ERROR: ', error);
      }

      requestAnimationFrame(loop);
    };

    loop(); // Call loop function to start the animation frame loop
  }
```

The component TensorCamera successfully calls handleCameraStream function because it prints this in my console

```
 LOG:  IN HANDLE CAMERA STREAM...
 LOG:  {}
 LOG:  LOOP ERROR:  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTypedArray' of undefined]
```

As you can see, logs prints an `empty {}`, then trycatch block catches the error

```
LOOP ERROR:  [TypeError: Cannot read property 'isTypedArray' of undefined]
```

Anyone have any idea why this is happening? The file containing the code is [here](https://pastebin.com/PyVXPGwC)

**Project package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "gk",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.21.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^4.15.0",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native": "^1.0.0",
    "expo": ">=50.0.0-0 <51.0.0",
    "expo-camera": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~15.4.2",
    "expo-gl": "~13.6.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.1",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.20.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.18",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.2",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}
```